# Python requests add header with opener

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I want to add custom headers to this Python request code:

```
import six
from six.moves.urllib import request
opener = request.build_opener(
request.ProxyHandler(
    {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:9000'}))
print(opener.open('http://example.com/data.json').read())
```

The opened URL reads the custom headers to reply to the requests appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
import requests as r
url = "http://example.com/data.json"
header = {"myheader": 123456}
proxies = {
 "http": "http://127.0.0.1:9000",
 "https": "http://127.0.0.1:9000",
}
data = r.get(url,headers=header,proxies=proxies)
data = data.json()
print(data)
```